# Allow users to have access to different features

Tags: configuration, saas

I wish to build a Saas in the future using angular. I have always wondered how to allow users to have access to different features depending on the different packages they pay for.

For example: bronze package allows user to send 100 emails.
             silver package allows user to send 200 emails.

This is a very simple example but I believe the concept will still apply.
So how do we differentiate between user accessibility to specific features?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some underlying framework - like Symfony - to build an api. Symfony with api-platform is a good choice.

Then you build your Angular app and send api-requests via fetch or axios. Symfony and api-platform handles in this case all the restriction stuff via voters and so on.

Comment: Thanks I shall do some research into this framework

Comment: that are multiple framworks symfony (with all other frameworks like doctrine) and api-platform.